# change style of expandable list

Tags: android, styles, expandablelistview

I Create my Expandable list.
Now I want to change style of list from below picture:
[image]

- to this picture:

[image]

I want to change the Icon of each group as shown in pictures. and change the line between each group. tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can set attributes like this:

```
 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/ParentLevel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:childDivider="@color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0sp"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

change
    android:divider="@color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0sp" as you want.

Comment: tnx for your answer, can you tell me how change indicator icon of groups??

Comment: You have to create custom raw xml for your  view.